# How to Block past date or selected dates in XamDateTimeInput

Tags: wpf, infragistics

I have infragistics **XamDateTimeInput** control. I want to prevent users to select some configured dates or past dates(Disable the dates). Here is the example which i found in a train booking site. They disabled the past dates.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the Infragistics control to test this, but from studying the [XamDateTimeInput doc](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/Silverlight/2012.1/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsSL5.Controls.Editors.XamDateTimeInput.v12.1~Infragistics.Controls.Editors.XamDateTimeInput_members.html) and the [ValueConstraint doc](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/Silverlight/2012.1/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsSL5.Controls.Editors.XamMaskedInput.v12.1~Infragistics.Controls.Editors.ValueConstraint_members.html), you should be able to set a min and max date by:

```
<XamDateTimeInput ...>
    <XamDateTimeInput.ValueConstraint>
        <ValueConstraint MinInclusive="Your min date" MaxInclusive="Your max date"/>
    </XamDateTimeInput.ValueConstraint>
</XamDateTimeInput>
```

I can't find a way to block a specific date range though. However, a few weeks ago I stumbled across this article on CodeProject, where the author has modified a regular WPF `DatePicker`. His solution also includes support for `Blackout Dates`:

[CodeProject: A couple of tricks when using the standard WPF .NET 4.0 DatePicker control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126762/A-couple-of-tricks-when-using-the-standard-WPF-NET)

You may use this post to modify your Infragistics `XamDateTimeInput` control. I can't test or provide an example here, as like I said, I haven't purchased their controls.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. 
Actually i want to block particular selected dates too. this will block all the dates between the given range.

Comment: @RashadAnnara I added some information about blocking a specific date range to my answer.